# How can I recreate this free floating/no gravity simulation?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I'm looking to create a very short animation of a number of objects in a kind of zero gravity/free floating situation like this...

[image]

the objects need to collide and not pass through each other. Does anyone have any useful simulation set ups that I could create. I'm assuming it begins with an emitter and some kind of force field but I'm very new to this type of animation so any step by step guides would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would first set the scene gravity to zero, but beyond that, duplicating multiple rigid body metal rods can be done different ways. I might set up one rod, and then use alt D to duplicate linked, possibly randomizing their rotary transformations afterwards. Another way is to use a particle system to generate lots of them, and then “make instances real.“ As a last note, depending on what you exactly want to happen, you might try using a turbulence field to randomize their orientations instead. That will ensure that they don’t intersect because the turbulence field actually operates within the physics simulation.